# How to bulk update drawing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I have this canvas class

```
public class DrawingCanvas : Canvas
    {
        private readonly Drawing _drawing;

        public DrawingCanvas(Drawing drawing)
        {
            _drawing = drawing;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);
            dc.DrawDrawing(_drawing);
        }
    }
```

And (a simplified version of) my main program

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
            var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            geometryGroup.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 100), 100, 100));
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 200), 100, 100));

            var geometryDrawing = new GeometryDrawing
            {
                Geometry = geometryGroup,
                Brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                    Colors.Blue,
                    Color.FromRgb(204, 204, 255),
                    new Point(0, 0),
                    new Point(1, 1)),
                Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 10)
            };

            geometryDrawing.Geometry = geometryGroup;
            drawingGroup.Children.Add(geometryDrawing);

            var canvas = new DrawingCanvas(drawingGroup);
            var window = new Window {Content = canvas};

            var timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle)
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
            };

            timer.Tick += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                foreach (var ellipse in geometryGroup.Children)
                {
                    var e = ellipse as EllipseGeometry;
                    e.Center = new Point(e.Center.X + 5, e.Center.Y);
                }
            };
            timer.Start();

            new Application().Run(window);
        }
```

As far as I understand, whenever a geometry is updated in a `DrawingGroup` the view is rendered and updated. It is probably more complicated than that. However, I don't want the `Canvas` to be updated for every change in the drawing. Instead, I want to update it, let's say, every 50 ms.

In Winforms, there is `Invalidate()` method in order to bulk update a drawing. Is there a similar way in WPF? Bulk updating `DrawingGroup` would be much more desirable, but I don't know either way.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking here. You are already updating the Drawing in a DispatcherTimer Tick handler that runs every 50 ms. The drawing will not be rendered until the Tick handler has finished each execution.

Comment: @Clemens I am running a foreach loop, If I have 5000 particles, would the drawing be updated in every single loop?

Comment: No, the drawing will not be rendered until the Tick handler has finished each execution. It runs in the UI thread.

Comment: @Clemens **The drawing will not be rendered until the Tick handler has finished each execution** If this is true that would be a relief. But why some people use WriteableBitmap in order to increa performance?

Comment: As a note, regardless of how many changes you make to any UI element, WPF won't render faster than its normal frame rate of 60 fps. It is retained mode graphics, not comparable to WinForms.

Comment: WriteableBitmap is typically used when you want to draw a large number of individual pixels. Using it for "graphics" like shapes etc. is odd. Maybe these people come from a pixel-graphics background and don't understand the vector graphics capabilities of WPF.

Comment: @Clemens Is it not suitable for games? I was thinking of rendering every frame to WriteableBitmap and showing it in Image control. I guess it was an overkill. Can you redirect me to a document that I can be sure that until DispatcherTimer event is finished WPF doesn't render the UI? If that's the case, your comment is the answer.

Comment: Maybe start reading here: [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview)